# NSProgressIndicator animation during intermediate state

Tags: macos, cocoa, animation, nsprogressindicator

I am showing a progress bar to show the progress of uploading data. When I finish the upload process, I have some finalizing steps and at this time I am planning to change the state of my progress bar to intermediate state (Just like what mac installer shows at the last moment of installation process). SO what I did was, I changed the state to intermediate. Now the progress bar is shown with inclined blue stripes. But it's not animating. How do I activate animation at this moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[NSProgressIndicatorInstance startAnimation:self]` will (re)start the animation and `[NSProgressIndicatorInstance stopAnimation:self]` will stop it again.

Comment: thanks :) I did the same thing in another way, basically I binded the animation property to one BOOL value, which I will be updating.